# Extracting latitude/longitude from javascript and passing to html form

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, html

I have the following problem

I use a google map inside an html form where the user can enter an address (autocomplete) and the marker goes to the place. The marker is draggable.

What I want is to **extract latitude and longitude and to pass the values to two different hidden fields** In order to end up to two text fields (decimal)

**The JavaScript**

```
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// 

function initAutocomplete() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: 37.9371157, lng: 22.9303688},
         zoom: 13,          
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

         // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({           
              draggable: true,
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));    

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
```

This code works well. Now **i need to extract latitude and longitude values and to pass them in a hidden field inside an html form**

```
input type="hidden" name="maps_latitude" id="maps_latitude" value=""
input type="hidden" name="maps_longitude" id="maps_longitude" value=""
```

maps_latitude and maps_longitude are two text fields in a cms (decimal) in order to get the values

Can anyone help how I need to modify the JavaScript and the hidden fields?

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly understanding your problem, you can get marker position using these functions :

After dragend :

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'dragend', function ( event ) {
    document.getElementById( "maps_latitude" ).value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById( "maps_longitude" ).value = this.getPosition().lng();
} );
```

on click :

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function ( event ) {
    document.getElementById( "maps_latitude" ).value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById( "maps_longitude" ).value = event.latLng.lng();
} );
```

OR

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function ( event ) {
    document.getElementById( "maps_latitude" ).value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById( "maps_longitude" ).value = this.getPosition().lng();
} );
```

Comment: Hello Vinni and than you for your response

Comment: well i placed it after the marker like that    map.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () 
   { 
   document.getElementById("maps_latitude").value = this.getPosition().lat(); 
   document.getElementById("maps_longitude").value = this.getPosition().lng(); 
   });

Comment: nothing happened ... also do you have any idea what will be passed to the hidden field as a value?            <input type="hidden" name="maps_latitude" id="maps_latitude" value="maps_latitude">

Comment: this is the code [link] http://openkorinthos.gr/index.php/profile2/new-entry2 [/link]

Comment: you can use this example  : https://jsfiddle.net/vinni0803/wk7kqnc2/   on click of red marker you will get lat long and if it works mark this as answer

Comment: Well, actually this example seems to have different purpose than what i want even though it's similar. The example shows lat and lng for every marker.

Comment: What i want is to extract lat and lng and to pass the values in two hidden fields "maps_latitude" and "maps_longitude". The piece of code that the Java Script shows above is taken from Google [link] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox [/link]. Since i am not Javascript master i am trying to understand where exactly i need to place the piece of code above inside Java Script (either After dragend or Click) in order to pass the values in the hidden fields